# How to Calculate the two Columns in Table in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, material-table

In Material Table, There are three columns, One is CashAdd , Expenses and Balance so I want to put the formula in Balance column like this :
**Balance = (CashAdd-Expenses)-previousBalance** in Balance column
So anybody please tell how to do in React with Hooks ?

```
    const [data, setData] = useState([
      {
        cashAdd:"",
        Expenses:"",
        BalanceRs:""
      }
    ]);  

useEffect(() => {

  data.find((item)=> {
    const balance = item.cashAdd -item.BalanceRs;
    //so how to find the last balance and calculate it
    //also how to update the state?

  })

}, [])
```

Comment: I think you can you a separate usestate hook for storing the previous balance.

Comment: @GopiKumarKaushik, never do something like this when there are easier ways, check my answer

Comment: I know that but if we store the previous balance separately then we can use that anywhere instead of only the setState function.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the previous state by using something like this:

```
setData((previousData) => {
  previousData.find((item) => {
    const balance = item.cashAdd -item.BalanceRs;
    // your code
  })
  return /*return new state here*/
})
```

Comment: i can't get it because its give me error in .find. Can you please tell me in the codesandbox ?(https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-autofocus-forked-mvusv8?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @HumailSaleem, can you share which error it gives you exactly?